# MySQL Index + Query Processing

Tags: mysql

Assume I have this table:

```
create table table_a (
    id int,
    name varchar(25),
    address varchar(25),
    primary key (id)
) engine = innodb;
```

When I run this query:

```
select * from table_a where id >= 'x' and name = 'test';
```

How will MySQL process it? Will it pull all the id's first (assume 1000 rows) then apply the where clause name = 'test'?

Or while it looks for the ids, it is already applying the where clause at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As id is the PK (and no index on name) it will load all rows that satisfy the id based criterion into memory after which it will filter the resultset by the name criterion. Adding a composite index containing both fields would mean that it would only load the records that satisfy both criteria. Adding a separate single column index on the name field may not result in an index merge operation, in which case the index would have no effect.

Comment: I'm not sure having seperate indexes for id and name will make the same performance impact with having a composite index. Are you sure about that?

Comment: @AtaS. - It will depend on the optimiser. It may chose to do an index merge in which case it will have a similar performance benefit to using a composite index, but it may not. - [Index Merge Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html)

Comment: Assume that table has multiple text columns, and I still run the same query, then like you said it will grab all the rows first, then apply the filter clause. In this case, the text columns are very expensive to be placed inside the memory. Is this correct?

Comment: It will depend massively on the size of the text columns and the number of records. These sorts of questions are often best answered by experimentation (using EXPLAIN as Mosty said). Adding the composite index on (name, id) is probably your best course of action.

Comment: I'm not sure I get you. My question is whether MySQL will pull the records first in memory then apply the filter later on. So, if a row has 20 columns, it will pull all those columns first in memory then apply the filter, right?

Comment: That is my understanding although it may be that there is some kind of optimisation that enables it to only read the data for columns referenced in the query. I am not sure how the entire process works. You would be better off asking on [DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have indexes on either column?  That may affect the execution plan.  The other thing is one might cast the 'x'::int to ensure a numeric comparison instead of a string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

For the best result, you should have a single index which includes both of the columns id and name.

In your case, I can't answer the affect of the primary index to that query. That depends on DBMS's and versions. If you really don't want to put more index (because more index means slow write and updates) just populate your table with like 10.000.000 random results, try it and see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can get information on how the query is processed by running [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) on the query.

If the idea is to optimize that query then you might want to add an index like:

```
alter table table_a add unique index name_id_idx (name, id);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can compare the execution times by executing the query first when the id comes first in the where clause and then interchange and bring the name first. to see an example of mysql performance with indexes check this out http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/02/indexes-in-mysql/